# Joomla paypal plugin post variables with special character not working

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

I am using joomla 2.5.4 and Virtuemart 2.0.6, When i try to do a payment with paypal, in paypal summary of order: Description is showing without special character. it shows like Nï¿½mero instead of Número.
How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to plugins/vmpayment/paypal/paypal.php

And search for this function plgVmConfirmedOrder()

You can see this form at last of this function

```
$html = '<html><head><title>Redirection</title></head><body><div style="margin: auto; text-align: center;">';
 $html .= '<form action="' . "https://" . $url . '" method="post"   name="vm_paypal_form">';
 $html.= '<input type="submit"  value="' . JText::_('VMPAYMENT_PAYPAL_REDIRECT_MESSAGE') . '" />';
 foreach ($post_variables as $name => $value) {

     $html.= '<input type="hidden" name="' . $name . '" value="' . htmlspecialchars($value). '" />';

 }
 $html.= '</form></div>';
 $html.= ' <script type="text/javascript">';
 $html.= ' document.vm_paypal_form.submit();';
 $html.= ' </script></body></html>';
```

Replace the form with this.

```
$html = '<html><head><title>Redirection</title></head><body><div style="margin: auto; text-align: center;">';
 $html .= '<form action="' . "https://" . $url . '" method="post"   name="vm_paypal_form">';
 $html.= '<input type="submit"  value="' . JText::_('VMPAYMENT_PAYPAL_REDIRECT_MESSAGE') . '" />';
 foreach ($post_variables as $name => $value) {

     $html.= '<input type="hidden" name="' . $name . '" value="' . htmlspecialchars($value). '" />';

 }
 $html.= '<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">';
 $html.= '</form></div>';
 $html.= ' <script type="text/javascript">';
 $html.= ' document.vm_paypal_form.submit();';
 $html.= ' </script></body></html>';
```

We added a line

```
 $html.= '<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">';
```

This works fine for me.